# Draw Beautiful Speech Bubbles in Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing, shapes

I am trying to create beautiful speech bubbles in swing but the result is not very good...I mean I want something better and more beautiful!

[image]

[image]

here is the code i'm using:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

public class BubbleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LeftArrowBubble leftArrowBubble = new LeftArrowBubble();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, leftArrowBubble);
        RightArrowBubble rightArrowBubble = new RightArrowBubble();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rightArrowBubble);
    }

    private static class LeftArrowBubble extends JPanel {

        private int strokeThickness = 5;
        private int padding = strokeThickness / 2;
        private int radius = 10;
        private int arrowSize = 6;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            final Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            graphics2D.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
            graphics2D.setColor(new Color(80, 150, 180));
            graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeThickness));
            int x = padding + strokeThickness + arrowSize;
            int width = getWidth() - arrowSize - (strokeThickness * 2);
            int height = getHeight() - strokeThickness;
            graphics2D.fillRect(x, padding, width, height);
            RoundRectangle2D.Double rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, padding, width, height, radius, radius);
            Polygon arrow = new Polygon();
            arrow.addPoint(14, 6);
            arrow.addPoint(arrowSize + 2, 10);
            arrow.addPoint(14, 12);
            Area area = new Area(rect);
            area.add(new Area(arrow));
            graphics2D.draw(area);
            graphics2D.dispose();
        }

    }

    private static class RightArrowBubble extends JPanel {

        private int strokeThickness = 5;
        private int padding = strokeThickness / 2;
        private int arrowSize = 6;
        private int radius = 10;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            final Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            graphics2D.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
            graphics2D.setColor(new Color(20, 130, 230));
            graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeThickness));
            int width = getWidth() - arrowSize - (strokeThickness * 2);
            int height = getHeight() - strokeThickness;
            graphics2D.fillRect(padding, padding, width, height);
            RoundRectangle2D.Double rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(padding, padding, width, height, radius, radius);
            Polygon arrow = new Polygon();
            arrow.addPoint(width, 6);
            arrow.addPoint(width + arrowSize, 10);
            arrow.addPoint(width, 12);
            Area area = new Area(rect);
            area.add(new Area(arrow));
            graphics2D.draw(area);
            graphics2D.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

any idea guys?

I want something like speech bubbles in viber (android version 5.0.0) but I don't know how to draw something like that...
can anyone help me?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Look into the shapes API

Comment: Use 2 Ellipse, and intersect them to create rounded triangle kind. And I think rounded rectangle is fine. Don't forget to set frame to create this rounded triangle.

Comment: The viber example you show has a light shadow. I guess this contributes most to what makes you consider it more beautiful.  Otherwise (apart from more rounded corners and a curved “outlet”) your own solution already comes pretty close.

Comment: @afzalex I think I can draw it with `GeneralPath`

Comment: Then what is your question. what you are wanting your program to do. Is it the fading behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally I draw it with `GeneralPath`...

[image]

close enough? :))

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    final Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    graphics2D.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
    graphics2D.setPaint(new Color(80, 150, 180));
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    path.moveTo(5, 10);
    path.curveTo(5, 10, 7, 5, 0, 0);
    path.curveTo(0, 0, 12, 0, 12, 5);
    path.curveTo(12, 5, 12, 0, 20, 0);
    path.lineTo(width - 10, 0);
    path.curveTo(width - 10, 0, width, 0, width, 10);
    path.lineTo(width, height - 10);
    path.curveTo(width, height - 10, width, height, width - 10, height);
    path.lineTo(15, height);
    path.curveTo(15, height, 5, height, 5, height - 10);
    path.lineTo(5, 15);
    path.closePath();
    graphics2D.fill(path);
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, you made it. But I wanna clear you that your question was unclear at that time, someone could help you with this. Please try to make your question clear next time. Even I thought that you are saying that you can make that thing with GeneralPath and you have some other problem.