# how to draw java chat Bubble speech?

Tags: java

hello for every one pls help me ,
i am trying to

### make Java Desktop app for chatting

,i want to add chat representation in my chat application's to make  UI **style messages bubble speech Conversation** so i want to draw by Java Code like this  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDwuc.png) pls help me the code or how to draw by java code like this ,
this my first post in https://stackoverflow.com/
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question and your time here I take it that you are not too experienced with java (I mean no offence).

Instead you can do as I did, which worked perfectly fine for such a situation:

I created a JLabel, and assigned it an ImageIcon, In the code example below you will see me creating two labels which where to be used as buttons, one up and one down arrow for a list:

```
private void buildPair() {
    //Make an ImageIcon Array (optional)
    ImageIcon image[] = new ImageIcon[2];
    //You create a new ImageIcon with the picture from your recouses, then you the the image and scale it, in this case its scaled to 20 by 20 pixel
    Image originalDown = new ImageIcon(ExtendedList.class.getResource("/Elements/Down Arrow Button.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    Image originalUp = new ImageIcon(ExtendedList.class.getResource("/Elements/Up Arrow Button.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    //Then I add the scaled images to a new ImageIcon and then add it to my ImageIgon arrat
    image[0] = new ImageIcon(originalDown);
    image[1] = new ImageIcon(originalUp);
    //Using an external Jlabel array i assing it with new Jlabel with this ImageIcon
    buttonPair[0] = new JLabel(image[0]);
    //I then add a custom event class, but you can make your own method or leave this out if its not needed
    buttonPair[0].addMouseListener(events);
    //And lastly i add this to my form
    this.add(buttonPair[0]);
    //and repeat for as many times as you need
    buttonPair[1] = new JLabel(image[1]);
    buttonPair[1].addMouseListener(events);
    this.add(buttonPair[1]);
}
```

Do not forget to import:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Mr.@simon-jensen ,i can to do it to make image in any way , but what i want is a call java graphics to draw every image by coding for example like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25822083/5799356)

Comment: I do understand that you wanted to draw this using code, but since it seemed a bit advanced I thought best to go with a more simpler solution, I however hope you found the answer you were looking for either with my power or in the referenced link you provided, good luck with your project.