# How do I add a running text in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a Java Tutorial for beginners, There's an avatar which will be talking, in a speech bubble. How do I make the words appear inside the speech bubble? I'm still new to Programming so I'm not sure how do I search for what I wanted. What I found was Marquee effect which isn't what I wanted.

Comment: i don't know if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821238/draw-beautiful-speech-bubbles-in-swing

Comment: Thanks! Other than the text bubble, how do I make the text appear from left to right? Not running text, words appearing

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3621417/230513)? If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: This will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617326/marquee-effect-in-java-swing

Comment: @trashgod the main question might be duplicate, but there is another question ( on the comment). I suggest that ruiru edits this question to make it clearer.

Comment: You can update this question or ask a different question.